# Get the key of an object from within the object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this which is a collection of key=>function pairs.

```
 var hashes = {
    "a": function () {
        console.log($(this));
    return 'Fanta';
  },
  'b': function () {
        console.log($(this));
    return 'Pepsi';
  },
  'c': function () {
        console.log($(this));
    return 'Lemonade';
  }
};

hashes["a"]();
hashes["b"]();
```

I want to get the name of the key from within the function i.e. I was expecting console.log($(this)) to return "a" for 1st function, "b" for 2nd function and so on.. But since hashes is calling the function, it returns hashes object.

Is there any way to get key of the object from within the function (I need only corresponding key to the function being called)

Comment: You can't pass the key to the function?

Comment: @limelights:  Do you mean like: hashes["a"]("a");

I can do it but I wanted to know if there is a way to do this without passing value.

Comment: There is no way that I'm aware of. The function doesn't actually belong to the `hashes` object or to the individual key, rather that object property holds a reference to the function. You could have other references to the function that aren't part of the object, e.g., `var x = hashes.a; x();`. (returns 'Fanta') If you give the functions names to match the keys you could try `arguments.callee.name`, but that's deprecated and won't work in strict mode.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks for your reply. I get you. But still, I will wait to see if there is any solution for this. I was using this as an alternative to switch case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var hashes = {
  'a': 'Fanta',
  'b': 'Pepsi',
  'c': 'Lemonade'
};

var logger = function( key, value ) {
  console.log( key );
  return value;
};

for ( var key in hashes ) {
  if ( hashes.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    var value = hashes[ key ];
    hashes[ key ] = logger.bind( null, key, value );
  }
}

hashes.a(); // "a"
hashes.b(); // "b"
hashes.c(); // "c"
```

[**Demo on JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/vuyogedasi/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Oh, wait.. I get your code now. Seems you are using 2 variables to achieve this.. But this will work...

Comment: Updated the code to use one `hashes` variable instead of two. Also removed dependency on lexical `this`.